# Breaking repository directories into two repositories, but keeping one as the main repository

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository which primarily consists of two directories: project_paper and project_package. I had one repository for them because I considered them a shared project. However, I now need to separate these two directories into two repositories and, ideally, I would like to make the project_package directory the repository for the current repository (if that makes sense). And while I'd love to keep the commit history for both of them, I hold the project_package commit history as more important to maintain.

So I want to go from:

```
proj_repo_1
|--project_package
|--project_paper
```

to

```
proj_repo_1
|--contents of project_package

proj_repo_2
|--contents of project_paper
```

Frankly, I haven't tried anything as I'm a novice with git and fear losing my work, but from what I searched with the vernacular I know I can't find a solution online that fits what I'm trying to do. I hope this is okay, but I'm posting the github repository below so you can actually see what I'm working with. In this case:

package_HPAStainR = project_package ; paper_test = project_paper.

https://github.com/tnieuwe/HPAstainR

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm more than willing to clarify anything, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you wan tthe `project_package` and `project_paper` folders in the two new repos? Or do you want the contents of these folders.

Comment: Sorry, I want the contents of the directory `project_package` in the original repository of `proj_repo_1`, meanwhile I want the contents of directory `project_paper` in a new repository. Does that make sense?

Comment: "I haven't tried anything as I'm a novice with git and fear losing my work" The nice thing about git is almost every command is reversable. Learnign how can greatly reduce this fear of loosing everything. I recommend reading the first three chapters of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to gain more confidence with your git skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain your entire history for both of the projects, you can clone the existing one. For all command-line examples in this project, I will prepend the command with a command prompt similar to what you see in Linux by default. It will be of the form `<directory>$ <command>`. I am assuming that you have a `/home/my_user/projects` folder that contains all of your coding projects and that the current project is in `projects/my_project`.

To start, go to the `projects` folder and clone `my_project` to `project_paper`:

```
~/projects$ clone my_project project_paper
```

Now you can either clone `my_project` to `project_package`, too, or just rename the `my_project` folder to `project_package`:

```
~/projects$ mv my_project project_package
```

Finally, you can rearrange the contents of each of these two repos however you wish. For example:

```
~/projects$ cd project_package
~/projects/project_package$ mv project_package/* .
~/projects/project_package$ rmdir project_package
~/projects/project_package$ git rm project_paper
~/projects/project_package$ git add .
~/projects/project_package$ git commit
```

and similarly for `project_paper`:

```
~/projects$ cd ../project_paper
~/projects/project_paper$ mv project_paper/* .
~/projects/project_paper$ rmdir project_paper
~/projects/project_paper$ git rm project_package
~/projects/project_paper$ git add .
~/projects/project_paper$ git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete project 1, commit, copy and paste in a different folder. Now you can push to a different repo.

Undelete project 1, delete project 2, commit, copy and paste in a different folder. Now you can push to a different repo too.

You will have duplicate commit history for both repositories, and people can still see content of the other project in your commit history, but now you have 2 different repos with commit history.

Maybe there is a better solution, hope this helps.

Comment: Just to clarify, locally delete `project_package`, commit, copy and paste the `project_paper` to a different folder. Un-delete `project_package`, delete `project_paper`, commit, and copy and paste the project to a new folder for it as well? Can I still use the old repository for `project_package` then?